# When re-sizing my browser or changing resolution body container jumping to right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, joomla

When re-sizing or changing resolution my content(main container) jumping to right approximately for 10 pixels.
Here is my website http://bmsc.tfei.info/
If you change the size to smaller it jumps to right.
Can someone help me why it is jumping?
I am developing joomla template using bootstrap and css.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He is jumping because your template is using twitter bootstrap as a base

*bootstrap-responsive.css* **Line 714**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    body {
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    }
```

change for

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    body {
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
    }
```

You should considere not use the bootstrap-responsive.css at all, because nothing on your website is responsive so there is no reason for using this file.

**Edit:** Problem solved removing the `bootstrap-responsive.css` from his template.

Comment: Nothing changed, still the same history. I changed to 0 as you said.

Comment: No you didn't, http://bmsc.tfei.info/media/jui/css/bootstrap-responsive.css is the same file without the 0 padding.

Comment: I am testing it in local machine and then will upload it... It is not working locally, so I do not want to upload it.

Comment: Dude, believe me if its not working locally is because you are doing something wrong, if you are talking about a 20px on the left and the right of your website when the screen get smaller size, that code above is what are you looking for.

Comment: I have uploaded it, check please.

Comment: Like i said its not jumping to the right anymore.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30408/discussion-between-vinicius-moraes-and-firdavs-kurbonov)